# phpMyAdmin doesn't login if session.auto_start is on

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I needed to set session.auto_start = 1 in my php.ini for a project, but right after setting it phpMyAdmin won't login anymore. When I change it back to 0, it works just fine. Do you have any clues how can I solve this while keeping  session.auto_start = 1?

Comment: i have the same issu, did you solved the problem?

Comment: I did not. Instead I switched from phpMyAdmin to MySQL WorkBench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not resolved it and it has been 1 year. Since the error, I quited using phpMyAdmin to MySQL WorkBench.